# Getting Errors when I tried to import Facebook SDK 4.0 for Android into Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have downloaded and unzipped the Facebook latest SDK-4.0. I have imported to Eclipse workspace but, there it's showing error in the project packages.

Comment: Please, add the error log, or screenshots. We can't help without any information.

Comment: Sorry, Due to reputation Stack overflow is not allowing me to upload images.

Comment: Upload it to other image hosting, or describe by text, what kind of error you are getting. You can also copy-paste error log here.